# Should I use smart pointers for my application and library?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

There are so much literature about smart pointers, I have read as much as I could. I just want a simple answer.

I have used raw pointer for my 3D renderer engines, and now I have to share some widgets between renderers, so here smart pointer comes. Please guide me should I update my entire software/library with smart pointer (std::shared_ptr)? What will be the cons in that case? I know the pros, just wanna know are there any cons? and what things are important that I should consider during the transformation from raw pointers to smart pointers? please be specific? Thanks.

Comment: Simple answer is:  yes.  Any time you are using dynamically-allocated objects, smart pointers will make avoiding memory leaks or dangling pointer errors much easier to avoid, with little (for shared_ptr) or no (for unique_ptr) runtime overhead.

Comment: you mean unique_ptr are better than shared_ptr?

Comment: unique_ptr is much more efficient (and often gets completely optimized away), but shared_ptr is more capable. Do everything you can with unique_ptr and then use shared_ptr for whatever's left. Never use a raw pointer without a very good reason.

Comment: Even just the exercise of thinking about which smart pointer type to use forces you to think about *ownership*, which is very important for building robust systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, they are a useful tool but not all tasks are suitable for a single tool. That said, here's a few things you should consider:

- Learning about smart pointers is a valuable skill. Knowing them is the base for applying them when appropriate and ignoring them in the few cases they are not.
- Smart pointers are more than just `std::shared_ptr`. There is also `std::unique_ptr`, also look into `std::make_shared`, `std::make_unique` (C++14) and `std::enable_shared_from_this` as a minimum.
- When passing `std::shared_ptr` as parameters, make sure you don't add synchronized, superfluous reference count manipulations, e.g., use `const std::shared_ptr<...>&`.
- Even when the standardized smart pointers are not the right tool, know how they work and create your own RAII wrappers - still better than full-blown, error-prone raw pointers.
- When interfacing existing C-style APIs, you can still often use smart pointers and only hand down the raw pointer to those APIs where needed, using `.get()` on the smart pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Much is to say about the pros of smart pointers and as other have already said I would recommend using them, where appropriate, in your applications.

When it comes to the API of libraries, I would say: It depends. If you are distributing your library in source form, then yes, you might use smart pointers in your API and your users might benefit from them. If you however want to distribute your library as DLL, smart pointers are not the right tool. That's because they are defined as templates and template classes are not distributable as DLLs. The users of your library would be forced to use the exact same compiler and template library as you did for the production of the DLL -- and that might be not what you want. Hence, for APIs of DLLs I would think twice before using smart pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the nice advice. I am little confused, I know some libraries, VTK, ITK, these libraries uses smart pointer and still we can compile as static or DLL, even those are fully compatible with linux unix. So what specifically are you saying? If I use smart pointers, I can't build dlls? are you saying smart pointers don't exists in linux unix mac etc?

Comment: What I am saying is that as most smart pointer classes are implemented as templates, these classes cannot be part of a DLL. So the user of your DLL has to have access to the very same definition of the smart pointer class that you have been using for your DLL, meaning: He must use the same compiler and collection of templates as you have been using to build the DLL.